# Arrays of Objects without standard constructor using Parameter Packs

Tags: c++, arrays, c++20, initializer-list, parameter-pack

I want to fill an std::array of size **N** with objects without a standard constructor.

```
std::array<non_std_con,N> myArray;
```

(It's `std::array<kissfft<float>, 64>` in my case, to be specific)

This results in the error

> error: use of deleted function ... *standard constructor*

### Setup

You can fill the array using an intializer list:

```
std::array<non_std_con,N> myArray{non_std_con{init1,init2},non_std_con{init1,init2},...}
```

The initializer list needs **N** objects.

And you can build an array using parameter packs:

```
template <class... Params>
auto constexpr build_array(Params... params)
{
    std::array<non_std_con, sizeof...(params)> myArray= {params...};
    return myArray;
}
```

### Question

Is there a way to use this the other way around and build a parameter pack out of
a single argument:

```
std::array<non_std_con,N> buildArray(inti1,init2);
```

This would build an array of **N** *non_std_con* where every object is initialized with
{init1,init2}

Thank you for your time

Comment: so, does a simple `auto my_array = std::array<non_std_con,N>{{init1, init2}};` work?

Comment: Unfortunatly no. This results in the error: could not convert ‘init1’ from ‘int’ to ‘non_std_con’

Comment: wait, is your type copyable?

Comment: I didnt write the object, I'm using a library. Only the constructor is defined in the source. So i guess the rest is defined by the compiler. [library](https://github.com/mborgerding/kissfft/blob/master/kissfft.hh)

Comment: could you simply actually use the type you're using in your code example? that'd take the guessing out of this?

Comment: I wanted my example to  be more generic. But my the code should look like this: ```std::array<kissfft<float>, 64> buildArray(2  << 14, false)```

Comment: hm, that should be copy-constructable. I take it `std::array<kissfft<float>,64> my_array{kissfft<float>(1<<15, false)}` doesn't work, either?

Comment: No this results in 64 errors of >error: could not convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>()’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘kissfft<float>’

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

namespace detail
{
    template <
        typename T,
        std::size_t ... Is
    >
    constexpr std::array<T, sizeof...(Is)> create_array(T value, std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    {
        // cast Is to void to remove the warning: unused value
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), value)...}};
    }
}

template<
    typename T,
    int N,
    typename... CtorAgrs
>
constexpr std::array<T, N> buildArray(CtorAgrs... args)
{
    using Array = std::array<T, N>;
    return detail::create_array<T>(T{args...}, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}


struct Foo{
    int a, b;
    constexpr Foo(int a, int b) : a(a), b(b)
    {
    }
};

int main() {
    constexpr auto array = buildArray<Foo, 10>(1, 2);

    for(const auto& f : array){
        std::cout << f.a;
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
}
```

or with C++-20 simply:

```cpp
template<
    typename T,
    int N,
    typename... CtorAgrs
>
constexpr std::array<T, N> buildArray(CtorAgrs&&... args)
{
    auto doBuildArray = [&]<std::size_t ... Is>(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
    ->  std::array<T, N>
    {
        // cast Is to void to remove the warning: unused value
        return {{(static_cast<void>(Is), T{args...})...}};
    };

    return doBuildArray(std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}
```